Trouble with Django migrations: No new migration files created despite all migrations applied
I am encountering an issue in my Django project where new migration files are not being created despite all migrations being applied. I have checked several possible causes, including database schema consistency, migration naming conflicts, and migration autodetection settings, but have not been able to resolve the issue.
Problem Details:
After running the makemigrations and migrate commands in Django, I expect to see new migration files created in my app's migrations directory. However, even though Django reports that all migrations are applied successfully, the expected migration files (0001_initial.py, 0002_something.py, etc.) are not generated.
Output of each migration cmd
Showmigrations output
 python manage.py showmigrations
Travello_2
 [X] 0001_initial
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial

Checked for existing migration files: Ensured that there are no existing migration files with conflicting names or in alternative locations that might prevent Django from creating new ones.
File Structure of App Migrations
File structure

What changes did you make to the models?

Are you running python manage.py makemigrations or are you making migrations for a specific app? Try giving the app that needs to make migrations to see if this fixes the issue (it has for me before).
